# How to change uGet download manager language?

Tags: language-support, download-manager, uget

My default uGet language is `persian` and want to change it to `EN`.I looked for `change language` option in uGet but i didn't find anything.  Also i don't want to change my locale to somewhere except Iran.So how can i change language?

Comment: put `env LANG=C` in front of your `uGet` invocation.

Comment: @waltinator what if we start uGet from GUI?

Comment: Edit a copy of `uGet.desktop` and change the `Exec=` line.

Comment: @waltinator tanx